# Mercurial Error 400: Bad Request with return code 255

Tags: version-control, mercurial, webstorm

Our repository consists of two branches a Default Branch(Where new features are developed) and Stable Branch(Where bug fixes are implemented). When a developer merges the Default Branch into the stable Branch and pushes all other developers receive a Error 400: Bad Request with return code 255 when attempting to pull or push changes.

We have multiple other repositories that reside on the same server but used by different teams that do not seem to suffer from the same issues. The repository in question is used by our web development team in conjunction with the WebStorm IDE.

This is the second time we have run into this problem with the same repository. The last time it happened we created a new repository and lost all of our history. Obviously this is not the ideal solution and is highly undesirable. We would like to determine what the cause is that is leading to the error.

When we clone the repository the problem is resolved temporarily until someone pushes a new change involving merging the two branches, then everyone but the person who pushed the change begins to receive the error.

The following is the output of an **hg --debug --traceback pull**

```
C:\Dev\HosedPrism>hg --debug --traceback pull
using http://mercurialserver01:8080/hg/rproxweb_OLD/
sending capabilities command
using auth.rprox.* for authentication
http auth: user jpalumbo, password ********
pulling from http://mercurialserver01:8080/hg/rproxweb_OLD/
query 1; heads
sending heads command
http auth: user jpalumbo, password ********
searching for changes
taking initial sample
searching: 2 queries
query 2; still undecided: 208, sample size is: 200
sending known command
http auth: user jpalumbo, password ********
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 88, in _runcatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 743, in _dispatch
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 514, in runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 833, in _runcommand
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 804, in checkargs
File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 740, in <lambda>
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 475, in check
File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 144, in wrap
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 475, in check
File "hgext\mq.pyo", line 3508, in mqcommand
File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 475, in check
File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 4743, in pull
File "mercurial\localrepo.pyo", line 1670, in pull
File "mercurial\discovery.pyo", line 46, in findcommonincoming
File "mercurial\setdiscovery.pyo", line 182, in findcommonheads
File "mercurial\wireproto.pyo", line 115, in plain
File "mercurial\wireproto.pyo", line 163, in _submitone
File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 170, in _call
File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 118, in _callstream
File "urllib2.pyo", line 406, in open
File "urllib2.pyo", line 519, in http_response
File "urllib2.pyo", line 438, in error
File "urllib2.pyo", line 378, in _call_chain
File "urllib2.pyo", line 1078, in http_error_401
File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 407, in http_error_auth_reqed
File "urllib2.pyo", line 963, in http_error_auth_reqed
File "urllib2.pyo", line 974, in retry_http_digest_auth
File "urllib2.pyo", line 406, in open
File "urllib2.pyo", line 519, in http_response
File "urllib2.pyo", line 444, in error
File "urllib2.pyo", line 378, in _call_chain
File "urllib2.pyo", line 527, in http_error_default
HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
abort: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

**hg verify** does not report any corruption in the repository.

I attempted to use the hg rollback command, per the following question [Mercurial keeps returning Error 400: Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093362/mercurial-keeps-returning-error-400-bad-request).
However this did not seem to resolve the problem.

Has anyone ever run into a similar problem? Or have any insight as to what the issue could be? I would be forever grateful for any help, not only to save our history but the prevent this from occurring again in the future.